# Clojure import java rename

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I was wondering if there is a way of renaming an imported Java Type in clojure.

Something like this:

```
(ns foo (:import java.util.List :as JList))
```

If not; Do I have to then reference the type as FQCN (fully qualified class name)?

UPDATE:

This example is a bit contrived, I know that I can reference Java classes once imported without FQCN.
The real problem is that I have a class that has the same name as a default imported class, 
for instance in java.lang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to rename a Java type.

Comment: But any ideas on how to import e.g. `org.jpl7.Float` witout the error `Float already refers to: class java.lang.Float ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you import the class, you no longer have to use the full name:

```
user> (import java.util.List) 
java.util.List  
user> List 
java.util.List
```

It adds the class name to the current namespace for you.